# Most compact and efficient way to find the disunion of two sets in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

To give a simple example, let's say I have two tables

```
  T1                      T2
=======                 =======
  Val                     Val
=======                 =======
   1                       1
   2                       3
   4                       4
   5                       5
                           6
```

The result set I want is

```
2
3
6
```

because those are the numbers contained in one but not the other. I know it can be done with something like

```
WITH cte1 (Val) AS (
    SELECT Val
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2
    ON T1.Val = T2.Val
    WHERE Val IS NOT NULL
),
cte2 (Val) AS (
    SELECT Val
    FROM T2
    LEFT JOIN T1
    ON T1.Val = T2.Val
    WHERE Val IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1
UNION WITH cte2
```

but is there a more compact and/or efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

a Full outer join should work, with an or clause.

```
SELECT isnull(t1.Val,t2.Val) [Val]
    FROM T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T1.Val = T2.Val
WHERE T1.Val is null OR T2.Val is null
```

Comment: This solution seems better in terms of performance, since most optimizers will sort the tables behind the scenes, before correlating them. No need for indexes on this solution. Upvoting it.

Comment: Elegant solution. I would replace ISNULL with COALESCE in case if the OP needs to apply it on several columns and not only two.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as :

```
select t1.* 
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.val = t1.val)
union all
select t2.* 
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t2.val = t1.val);
```

Comment: As a side note, if you have big sets of numbers, it's advisable to create indexes: `create index ix1 on t1 (val);` and `create index ix2 on t2 (val);`

Comment: this is almost exactly what the OP did, without the CTE wrapper.

Comment: @DanielE. OP didn't use `exists`